# Use msysgit with Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, github, msysgit

I have a initialized a remote repository using NetBeans. Most things I need to do can be done within netbeans, but most tutorials online use the command line. Can I setup msysgit to work with the existing local repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I setup msysgit to work with the existing local repositories?

It's simple: [Download and install msys git](http://msysgit.github.io/), this will integrate some git options to your windows explorer. That's all to do.

Just open your project's directory and you can open a *Git Bash* (= a terminal ready for git usage).

Now you can use NetBeans (and it's git) together with the one from msys - choose whatever you prefer, it doesn't matter which one you use.

**See also:**

- [MSys Git Wiki](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki)
- [FAQ](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)
- [Installation instruction](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/InstallMSysGit)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how to set the directory to use as the local repo, this solved it!

Comment: If your problem is solved, please click the green tick (= accept answer) to indicate this.